# Java singleton design pattern vs global variable

Tags: java, design-patterns, static, global-variables

I have developed a "Quiz application in java", which have many features like quiz conduction, instant reporting features, students can post their doubts and all.

I want to maintain the log of the number of students requested for quiz, the number of students that submitted the response, the total active students and some other details.

I am using a Global class which has static variables to keep these details. Is it correct way to maintain this or should I want to use the Singleton design pattern ?

Kindly give me pros and cons of both and which one to use and when?

Comment: You are using eager initialization of your data structure (Say List of candidates) which seems similar to Singleton. So what your question is?

Comment: @ almas shaikh, as for now im using static instant to keep these details inside a class, is it correct way im doing r i have to use singleton DP?

Comment: Have you seen how Singleton implemented? It's worth you know how singleton is implemented and then you compare with yours.

Comment: Thanks, @almas shaikh, Yes while seeing the singleton implementation only i got this question in my mind. That's why i raised this question which is best to use in my case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Long story short: by using global variables you're breaking OOP rules (encapsulation). You will keep using them until your code becomes one big mess.
So instead of using global variables I would go for singleton (but make sure it is thread safe). Neither solutions are great thought.

P.S. There is a lot of information on the internet:

- [Should I use global variables here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14628831/should-i-use-global-variables-here)
- [How to create a manager class without global variables nor singletons?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/179763/how-to-create-a-manager-class-without-global-variables-nor-singletons)
- [Why are static variables considered evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026507/why-are-static-variables-considered-evil)
- [Avoid Global Variables, Environment Variables, and Singletons](https://sites.google.com/site/michaelsafyan/software-engineering/avoid-global-variables-environment-variables-and-singletons)

Comment: Your 4th link `Singleton design pattern...` lead me to a virus / ad infested website.